# How to serve localhost font files using nginx

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nginx, fonts, webserver, glyphicons

I have a webapp which I'm using:

- AngularJS + Bootstrap (3.3.5)
- NGINX 1.6.2 (to serve static files and web related artifacts)
- GLASSFISH 4

I have my application served via NGINX and using redirect for JSON requests for data to GLASSFISH app server via NGINX configuration.

When I try using bootstrap Glyphicon hosted locally via NGINX and the above configuration only the plus, minus and letter icons display properly, all the rests display as empty boxes and I get the following message in my browser debug tool:

```
downloadable font: WOFF2: Failed to read 'length' or it does not match the actual file size (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1)

downloadable font: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1)

downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1) 

downloadable font: incorrect file size in WOFF header
```

I believe this is a NGINX font hosting related problem, as when I disable NGINX and host all the files directly from CDN or Glassfish the Glyphicons display correctly.

Can someone shed some light on the nginx configuration?

Comment: cURL that font, with headers: does your nginx add a `content-length` header with a value that does not match the actual byte length of the font?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans When I inspect the request using a browser debugging tool I get HTTP 200 OK, Response Headers: Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 116427
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 05:20:34 GMT
Etag: "562f07a0-1c6cb"
Last-Modified: Tue, 27 Oct 2015 05:12:00 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0  -----> Obs: the real file has 64,464  bytes

Comment: Don't put that in a comment: edit the post so everyone can see this new and insightful information immediately =) That said, clearly the content length is wrong, so the next step would be to find out what part of your nginx config controls content length headers, and why it's generating the wrong values (which probably means closing this question, doing some searching, and if you can't find the answer, opening a new question about that instead)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how to close the question ? Basically my question should be how to serve font files hosted locally using nginx, since using CDN all works fine.

Comment: you can either delete the question (Stackoverflow does not do "closed" questions, only questions with answers, or deleted question, to prevent search engines from finding no longer necessary questions), or you can edit the question to have a new title and content, to match what you want to know about.